# true dependence Question

Tags: computer-architecture

Let's Have

```
i1. lw $s2,0($s1)
i2. lw $s1,40($s6)
i3. sub $s6,$s1,$s2
i4. add $s6,$s2,$s2
i5. or $s3,$s6,$zero
i6. sw $s6,50($s1)
```

> what is the true dependence for register $s2 ?

i find 2 
i1 -> i3 and i1->i4

> what is the true dependence for register $s1 ?

i find 1 
i2 -> i3

> what is the true dependence for register $s6 ?

i find 2 
i4 -> i5 
i4 -> i6 ( i know that store instruction read register before store in it ! or i'm wrong ? )

---

Question 2 :
if we have some thing like that

```
i1. add $s6,$s3,$s4
i2. add $s5,$s1,$s2
i3. add $s6,$s5,$s7
i4. add $s8,$s6,$s9
```

> and we want to calculate true dependence for register $s6

it just 1 ? i3 -> i4 ? 
or 2 ? i1 -> i4 and i3 -> i4 ? 
in other words ? we calculate just the last write on register or all ?

Answer (score 0):

Only the most recent write counts.

For example in Q2, i4 cannot directly depend on the result of i1 because \$s6 was overwritten between them, so the result of i1 is not available. When a register is overwritten, from then on no instruction can depend on its old value, in the sense that instructions decoded later than the write necessarily refer to values at least as old as the write.

That is indeed the core principle that register renaming is based on, registers can be renamed on write precisely because it is only the most recent value that can be referred to by newer instructions. The name-relationship between i1 and i4 does not survive renaming, i3 would give \$s6 a new name and it is that name which i4 would see, not the old name allocated by i1. In fact when i3 retires, the name allocated by i1 can be freed and reused, because it is known that no newer instruction could refer to the result of i1 anymore and since i3 is the oldest instruction in the machine (it's retiring) that means that no instruction currently in the machine is referring to it either.